# Passing a HashMap with object as Key and List of objects as Value to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jstl

I basically have an object to which there is a list of other objects associated. Like say, every country object has a list of its state objects in a HashMap. I wanna be able to pass this hashmap to my jsp and access the attributes of the key (which is country) and also its value's (list of its states). Using JSTL, I might use ${map.value.name}, etc to access the states' info. But how can I access the attributes of the key, i.e., country name, continent etc. Would ${map.key.name} etc work?

Regards

Comment: Why not just try it? What is the result if you do it?

Comment: You are right. It worked straight away. I wasn't confident about it but I should tried it before posting here. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont keep only country name as a `string` key.

Keep country `object` as a key and list of state objects as a value. So you can get all properties of both classes.